# React Hooks: Why I have this output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm studying React hooks but i am not able to understand why I got this output in the console. Someone with great heart could explain in detail the "running execution" oh these hooks?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function Homepage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    console.log("useEffect not executed");
    setState("hello")
  }, []);
  if (!state) {
    console.log("state not defined");
    return <div>State undefined</div>;
  }
  return <div>ciao</div>;
}
export default Homepage;
```

console output:
state not defined
state not defined
useEffect
useEffect not executed
useEffect
useEffect not executed

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's a combination of [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) double invoking the function body twice as a way to help you [detect unexpected side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - ***Function component bodies*** <-- this
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

remounting the component to [ensure reusable state](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state)

> To help surface these issues, React 18 introduces a new
> development-only check to Strict Mode. This new check will
> automatically unmount and remount every component, whenever a
> component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on
> the second mount.

and the `useEffect` hook being called at the end of the render cycle.

```
function Homepage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect"); // logs second as expected side-effect
    console.log("useEffect not executed");
    setState("hello");
  }, []);

  if (!state) {
    console.log("state not defined"); // logs first as unintentional side-effect
    return <div>State undefined</div>;
  }

  return <div>ciao</div>;
}
```

...

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import Homepage from "./Homepage";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Homepage />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

### Explaining the logs

console output:

```
state not defined      // <-- initial render
state not defined      // <-- double invocation of function body
useEffect              // <-- effect at end of initial render
useEffect not executed // <-- effect at end of initial render
```

...unmount/mount

```
useEffect              // <-- effect at end of render
useEffect not executed // <-- effect at end of render
```

Comment: so is a sort of "undesired" effect under the hood(almost for what i'm understanding)?

Comment: @ValerioRampa More like a way to help detect undesired effects.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs when the page renders and the other functions execute before `useEffect` so your code runs the `if (!state)` first then `useEffect` runs and state sets to "hello"; here is a link to fully understand useEffect hook: [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html); Good luck;

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is running before the useEffect even tho is after it, you need to put both divs inside the return and remove the if

```
   return (
     {!state ? <div>State undefined</div> : <div>ciao</div>}
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `state not defined` first render of your component Homepage
2. `state not defined` 2nd render
3. `useEffect useEffect not executed` your component is mounted, so the useEffect hook is triggered.
4. `useEffect useEffect not executed` here your component rerender with the state `hello` the useEffect hook is triggered again

In practice, useEffect hook runs at minimum following your dependency array. Here your set `[]` so the useEffect hook runs when the component mounts, but sometimes it can still be triggered.